# Filter Data Columns by Other Columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am doing an analysis of tweets, I have a dataframe `df1`
that has a single variable with the text of the tweet and I have another dataframe `df2` that contains 2 variables, the first a word with sentiment and the second with the value of that sentiment.

I would like to create a new dataframe that extracts only the tweets where it finds the word of that feeling and put the value on it.

```
print(df1)
    0     @Brenamae_ I WHALE SLAP YOUR FIN AND TELL YOU ...
    1    Metin Şentürk Twitterda @metinsenturk MUHTEŞEM...
    2    RT @byunghns:  I LOVE #틴탑 SO MUCH #쉽지않아 IS GO...
    3    que hdp maicon lo que le hizo a david luiz jaj...

print(df2)
        1       2
0   abandoned  -2
1    abandons  -2
2    abducted  -2
```

Comment: I don't see how df2 is created from df1, none of those words are there

Comment: @Kenan: presumably this is a snippet, and the actual dataframes are longer. (Because we see at least 10 non-stopwords in df1, so df2 must be longer than 10 rows.)

Comment: Esteban: you need to **split the strings from each row in `df1` into a list or array**, presumably  you also want to do lowercasing, punctuation removal, and **exclude stopwords**. See e.g. [tag:nltk] or [tag:spacy]. There are many tutorials and blogs, but asking for them is offtopic on SO.

Comment: Can you please give us a proper reproducible example ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) for df2, since 'abandoned', 'abandons', 'abducted'  don't occur anywhere in your df1?

Comment: This question isn't well-defined ('Needs clarity'), **what value do you want assigned if a sentence from df1 contains multiple words from df2 with different sentiments?** (e.g. what if 'whale', 'slap', 'tell' all occur in df2 and have different sentiments? Do you want the average? a list or array of all sentiment-values in that row?)

Comment: Hi everyone, What is required is to obtain the column 'text' from the tweet dataset and evaluate if the sentiment exists in the other dataset 'sentiments' and if the word exists, assign it the value that corresponds to it.
Tweets that do not have text should be removed, and when debugging the tweet does not find sentiment, assign 0 as value.
https://github.com/emadrigals104/Analisis-de-Sentimientos.git

Answer (score 0):

```
First DF:
name: dfTweet
columns: [tweet]

Second DF:
name: dfSentiment
columns: [sentiment, value]

newDF = pd.DataFrame(columns = [tweet, value])
indexSentTweet = [] 
    
for indexSent, sent in enumerate(dfSentiment):
    indexValueTweet = [[dfTweet['tweet'].iloc[index], dfSentiment['value'].iloc[index]] for index, x in enumerate(dfTweet['tweet'].str.contains(sent)) if x] # List comprehension to reduce the number of "for".

newDF = newDF.append(pd.DataFrame(indexValueTweet, columns = ['tweet', 'value']))
```

I changed the column names to be easily understandable.

Comment: I tried to use your code but I did not execute the loop. I uploaded the exercise to my repository with its original datasets.
https://github.com/emadrigals104/Analisis-de-Sentimientos.git

Comment: @EstebanMadrigal, I recommend you update your question to add the code in github here, to make sure the information will not disappear. In your code, at the line 11 add the following code dfTweet = pd.DataFrame(dfTweet). Try again and check if it'll work. I tested here and don't see any problem.

Comment: I also uptade the code in my answer newDF = newDF.append(pd.DataFrame(indexValueTweet, columns = ['tweet', 'value']))